# Complementary compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a topological space having the property that whenever a subset $A$ of $X$ is compact, then $X\setminus A$ is compact too. Is every subset of $X$ compact?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Since $\emptyset$ is compact, $X$ is compact, so every closed subset of $X$ is compact, so every open subset of $X$ is compact. If every open subset of $X$ is compact, then every subset of $X$ is compact. That is, every family of open sets in $X$ has a finite subfamily with the same union.

Comment: How exactly do you get from every open set is compact to every set is compact?  I don't see your resoning here.

Comment: Take any set $A \subset X$. Choose an arbitrary open cover $\mathfrak{U}$ for it. Then the union $U:= \bigcup \mathfrak{U}$ of the sets in the open cover is open in $X$, and hence compact. Therefore there is a finite subcover $\mathfrak{F} \subset \mathfrak{U}$ for $U$. Then $\mathfrak{F}$ is also a finite subcover of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ itself is compact, hence Hausdorff. Singletons are compact, hence their complement is compact and closed, which makes singletons open and $X$ discrete. But then $X$ must be a finite discrete space, whence the claim.

Comment: How does compact imply Hausdorff? There are plenty of compact spaces which are not Hausdorff.

Comment: A space with the trivial topology is compact but not Hausdorff, not even $T_1$.

Comment: @Shalop: Some people, ultimately influenced by Bourbaki, I believe, reserve the term *compact* for what you and I would describe as *compact Hausdorff*; their term for our *compact* is *quasi-compact*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Interesting. I was wondering why someone as refined as Hagen would make such a mistake, but now I see that it was just a misunderstanding on my part.